# how to render html text in ASP.NET nshtml and Razor if it has model values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a variable with html text and model values

```
var text = "<h1> hello @Model.firstName @Model.lastName </h1>"
```

and in cshtml I have

```
@Html.Raw(text)
```

my code looks like

```
    @model TextModel
@{
     var text = Viewbag.text
 }
 ...
 <div>
      @Html.Raw(text)
 </div>
```

what it renders is "hello @model.firstName @model.lastName"
but what I want is "hello Jack James"
I don't know what can I do ?

Comment: You should really show us a true example of the code instead of a sample, since with your sample it would be as simple as vhr's answer. We cannot be sure what is going wrong if there is no clear code we can look into.

Comment: yeah sorry I  added a sample of my code

Comment: Where is this `viewbag` created? And where do you assign a value to it. Also why are you using a `viewbag` instead of a normal POCO class? You noted that this was webdata so i suppose it is to keep the solution dynamic. You should probably add the first and lastname to the `viewbag` as either variables or put them in the string you pass to `Viewbag.text`.

Comment: it's created in an other controller and the text is from an online source it's a view bag because that's the function RenderAsync of razorTemplatEngine it takes template path model and view bag as dictionary

Comment: Are you able to manipulate the items before they become part of the viewbag? If so you could simply use string interpolation there, and adding it to the viewbag. This makes it so you don't have to manipulate the text in the view

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var text = $"<h1> hello {Model.firstName} {Model.lastName} </h1>";
```

and then:
`@Html.Raw(text)`

Edited: Not sure what your CSHTML looks like, but it should work (providing it looks something like this):

```
@model YourModel
@{
     var text = $"<h1> hello {Model.firstName} {Model.lastName} </h1>";
 }
 ...
 <div>
      @Html.Raw(text)
 </div>
```

Comment: unfortunately  not working because here I used the text variable just to simplify the problem the html text is coming from an online source I tried to change the text there like you suggested but it will renders to $"hello {Model.firstName} {Model.lastName}"

Comment: thank you so much but my variable doesn't look like that that's probably why it didn't  work sorry I added a sample of my code

Comment: @EsraDamek I see now. you have to format your text in a place where you are setting the "Viewbag.text" (probably your controller), or if it's not possible (e.g. you're not allowed to change it), do some replacement like "text = Viewbag.text.Replace("@model.firstName", Model.firstName)" which is not very nice

Comment: exactly because I don't only have these variables but many. my colleagues suggested that I should do a function that creates a cshtml template during runtime that load the text there save in temp files and then use it in the RenderAsync function of razorTemplatEngine not sure though if it will work out or not

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `@Model` to replace `@model`:

```
var text = "<h1> hello @Model.firstName @Model.lastName </h1>"
```

**Update:**
Since you are using ViewBag in backend,here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class TestModel {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }

    }
```

C# code:

```
TesstModel model=new TestModel{firstName="f",lastName="l"};
var text = "<h1> hello "+model.firstName+" "+model.lastName+" </h1>";
```

Comment: it was a typo sorry I was actually using Model but still not working

Comment: Won't this just return the same issue? Since the `@Model.firstName` and `@Model.lastName` values are never accessed? @vhr's  answer is correct

Comment: unfortunately @vhr's answer is also not working because here I used the text variable just to simplify the problem the html text is coming from an online source I tried to change the text there like he suggested but it will renders to $"hello {Model.firstName} {Model.lastName}"

Comment: Could you show how this text is received from the online source? We cannot help if we cannot see what you are actually receiving/working with

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend manipulating the string before you pass it to the view.

**Controller:**

```
{
    //inside of the get function
    var person = //call to get the data
    var text = $"<h1> hello {person.firstName} {person.lastName} </h1>"
    //add `text` to the viewbag

}
```

**View:**

```
<div>
    @Html.Raw(Viewbag.text)
</div>
```